# std::thread constructor with no parameter

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread), the
`std::thread` constructor with no parameter means:

> Creates new thread object which does not represent a thread.

My questions are:

1. Why do we need this constructor? And if we create a `thread` using this constructor, how can we "assign" a thread function later?
2. Why don't we have a "run(function_address)" method so that when constructed with no parameter, we can specify a function to "run" for that `thread`.
3. Or, we can construct a `thread` with a callable parameter (function, functors, etc.) but call a "run()" method to actually execute the thread later. Why is `std::thread` not designed in this way?

Comment: threads are movable, hence swappable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your question suggests there might be some confusion and it would be helpful to clearly separate the ideas of a *thread of execution* from the `std::thread` type, and to separate both from the idea of a "thread function".

- A *thread of execution* represents a flow of control through your program, probably corresponding to an OS thread managed by the kernel.
- An object of the type `std::thread` can be associated with a *thread of execution*, or it can be "empty" and not refer to any *thread of execution*.
- There is no such concept as a "thread function" in standard C++. Any function can be run in a new *thread of execution* by passing it to the constructor of a `std::thread` object.

> 1. why do we need this constructor?

To construct the empty state that doesn't refer to a *thread of execution*. You might want to have a member variable of a class that is a `std::thread`, but not want to associate it with a *thread of execution* right away. So you default construct it, and then later launch a new *thread of execution* and associate it with the `std::thread` member variable. Or you might want to do:

```
std::thread t;
if (some_condition) {
  t = std::thread{ func1, arg1 };
}
else {
  auto result = some_calculation();
  t = std::thread{ func2, arg2, result };
}
```

The default constructor allows the object `t` to be created without launching a new *thread of execution* until needed.

> And if we create a thread using this constructor, how can we "assign" a thread function later?

You "assign" using "assignment" :-)

But you don't assign a "thread function" to it, that is not what `std::thread` is for. You assign another `std::thread` to it:

```
std::thread t;
std::thread t2{ func, args };
t = std::move(t2);
```

Think in terms of *creating a new thread of execution* not "assigning a thread function" to something. You're not just assigning a function, that's what `std::function` would be used for. You are requesting the runtime to create a new *thread of execution*, which will be managed by a `std::thread` object.

> 2. Why don't we have a "run(function_address)" method so that when constructed with no parameter, we can specify a function to "run" for that thread.

Because you don't need it. You start new threads of execution by constructing a `std::thread` object with arguments. If you want that thread of execution to be associated with an existing object then you can do that by move-assigning or swapping.

> 3. Or, we can construct a thread with a callable parameter(function, functors, etc.) but call a "run()" method to actually execute the thread later. Why std::thread is not designed in this way?

Why should it be designed that way?

The `std::thread` type is for managing a *thread of execution* not holding a callable object for later use. If you want to create a callable object that can be later run on a new *thread of execution* there are lots of ways to do that in C++ (using a lambda expression, or `std::bind`, or `std::function`, or `std::packaged_task`, or a custom functor type). The job of `std::thread` is to manage a *thread of execution* not to hold onto a callable object until you want to call it.

Answer (score 4):

The default constructor is provided such that an "empty" `thread` object can be created. Not all `thread` objects will be associated with a thread of execution at the time of construction of said object. Consider when the `thread` is a member of some type and that type has a default constructor. Consider another case that the `thread` type has no concept of a "suspended" thread, i.e. it can't be created in a suspended state.

The `thread` type doesn't have a "run" method of some sort since the one of the original design decisions (IIRC) was to have a "strong" association between the `thread` object and the thread of execution. Allowing `thread`s to be "moved" makes that intent clearer (in my opinion). Hence moving an instance of a `thread` object to an "empty" object is clearer than attempting to "run" a `thread`.

It is conceivable that you can create a wrapper class of some sort that offers the "run" method, but I think this may be a narrower use case, and that can be *solved given the API of the `std::thread` class*.

Comment: thanks, @Niall, but why the original design favors a "strong" association in the first place? What's the benefit of it?

Comment: A lot of the discussion at the time was around what to do with an "unjoined" thread once the object goes out of scope? Given that there was no real consensus on what to do, the result as that `std::terminate` be called since that provided the "safest" outcome. I.e. if the programmer intended it to be detached form the running thread, then they need to be explicit on this, and a "join" in the destructor could lead to unintended deadlocks.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Maybe lets firsts comment on the very last part:

> 3.2 Why std::thread is not designed in this way?

I don't know why exactly (there are surely advantages and disatvantages - see Jonathan Wakely's answer for a more details about the rational behind it), but it seems that c++11 `std::thread` is modelled much closer to pthreads than e.g. QT's or Java's `QThread/Thread` classes, which might be the source of your confusion.

As to the rest of your questions:

> 1.1 why do we need this constructor?

You might want to create a `std::thread` variable but don't directly start a thread (e.g. a class member variable or an element of a static array, es shown by alangab). It's not much different to an `std::fstream` that can be created without a filename.

> 1.2 And if we create a thread using this constructor, how can we "assign" a thread function later?

For example:

```
std::thread myThread;

// some other code

myThread = std::thread(foo());
```

> 2. Why don't we have a "run(function_address)" method so that when constructed with no parameter, we can specify a function to "run" for that thread.

I don't know, why it was designed like this, but I don't see the benefit a `run` method would have compared to above syntax.

> 3.1 Or, we can construct a thread with a callable parameter(function, functors, etc.) but call a "run()" method to actually execute the thread later.

You can simulate this by creating a lambda or `std::function` object and create the thread when you want to run the function.

```
auto myLambda = [=]{foo(param1, param2);};
// some other code
std::thread myThread(myLambda);
```

If you want to use the syntax you describe, I'd recommend to write your own `Thread` wrapper class (should only take a few dozen lines of code) that (optionally) also ensures that the thread is either detached or joined upon destruction of the wrapper, which is - in my opinion - the main problem with `std::thread`.

Answer (score 2):

The default constructor gives you then possibility to create array of threads:

```
thread my_threads[4];

for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
   thread temp(func,...);
   my_threads[i]=move(temp);
}
```

the thread created with default costructor "become" a "real" thread with the move costructor.

You can use thread with standard container if you need/like.